# When to start drafting a paper?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process

I am a second year Molecular Engineering PhD student and I am a ways away from having enough data to publish, but I know where I want my research to go and I have a good idea of the data I'll need to gather to get to that point. I've been told by at least one professor that you should start drafting a paper fairly early on in the research process, and I think doing so would at least help keep the research focused. On the other hand, I can see how starting the writing process too early could take time away from active research. It could also be limiting if research objectives ever need to change.

For those who have already written and published papers, when is the appropriate time to start drafting? How early is too early?

Comment: Yesterday. Even better, the day before yesterday.